# Screen Scrape using Phantomjs, results stored in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phantomjs, casperjs

I am looking to scrape this website: http://www.machinerytrader.com/list/list.aspx?ETID=1&catid=1002

I initially tried to use PHP to do this, but discovered that the body html is encrypted.  And so it appears this html is best accessed using a headless webkit like phantomjs.

My question is a general one: what is the best way to scrape this data in PhantomJS and then store that data in MySQL?

I have not seen any examples of this transition online and so have nothing to work off of.

UPDATE:

After some reading, I'm thinking it might make sense to use CasperJS and its download function to store the raw html locally and then just parse that using PHP later... but this approach is pretty roundabout...

Comment: What is your current code in PhantomJS ?

Comment: I've just been doing examples of phantomjs and casperjs to get a feel for them... My question is general, I'm just trying to find out if what I'm aiming to do is possible in phantomjs yet and maybe get a link to an example if it is

Comment: You are right about CasperJS, but I don't see a need in parsing result in PHP, because you can do it in CapserJS and even post extracted data on the fly to an auxiliary web-server (such as localhost), if you want, for example, store the data in a DB.

Comment: @stan Thanks Stan! Would you mind sharing a link to an example script of this process?

Comment: I did a project more than year ago, so it used a version of CasperJS which is outdated now. It's a series of CapserJS step-functions with self.click, self.xpathSelector, self.querySelectorContent, etc. methods.

Comment: Ah, yes. And about posting results, I used a page (created by new WebPage();) to `open` my server URL with aquired statuses in parameters. The request to the page was performed from onStepComplete event handler.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the info, you can just simply call a site controlled by you and store the data in the DB using a post request

```
casper.then(function(){
    casper.open("www.mipage.com/saveIntheDBonPost.php", {
        method: 'post',
        data:{              
            'title': ''+globalInfo.title,
            'body': ''+globalInfo.body
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you absolutely can't process the HTML from PHP, I would recommend that you have PhantomJS or CasperJS output XML/JSON to a file and then parse the XML/JSON from PHP. With scrapers that I've built in PhantomJS in the past, I've processed all HTML and stored relevant data into objects that I then transformed into XML/JSON. JSON is the easiest to consume and more light weight than XML in my experience. It's extremely easy to consume in PHP too since PHP has the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.